# Request library python, return session in method

Tags: python, session, post, get, request

Trying to return a request libary session in a method in python...
Would seem pretty simple, my script works fine and then I clean it up into a class and methods and it will not work, seems the session cant be returned from a method? Rather confused for I am sure this should work like this.

This is the code before the change it it works fine:

```
import requests

httpHeaders = { 'Host' : 'www.somesite.com',
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0',
    'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate',
    'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
    'Referer' : 'https://blah.someloginsite.com/logon',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length' : '59',
    'Referer' : 'someurl.com'}

postContent = { 'UserName': 'blabhbhbhb',
    'Password': 'qwerty', 
    'submit' : '', 
    'returnUrl' : ''}

s = requests.Session()
s.post('https://blah.someloginsite.com/logon', data=postContent, headers=httpHeaders)

param = {'someID': '225', 'anotherID': '0'}
r = s.post('https://someurl/doactionthatneedslogin', data=param)

print r.status_code
print r.headers['content-type']
print r.encoding
print r.text
```

Above code works fine, but when I break it down into a class and functions / methods it will not work. Now I clean the code up and it doesn't work, seems I can't return a session in request libary but I'm sure I can... ?

```
import requests


class doit():

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        print "test"
        spSession = self.getSession(username, password) 
        self.doAction(spSession, 33, 4)     

    #Initializes session 
    def getSession(self, username, password):
        httpHeaders = {SAME AS ABOVE BLAHBLAHBLAH}

        postContent = { 'UserName': username ,
            'Password': password , 
            'submit' : '', 
            'returnUrl' : ''}

        s = requests.Session()
        s.post('https://someurl.com/logon', data=postContent, headers=httpHeaders)      
        return s

    def doAction(self, spSession, someid,anotherid):
        param = {'someid': someid , 'anotherid': anotherid}
        r = spSession.post('https://someurl/doactionthatneedslogin', data=param)

        print r.status_code
        print r.headers['content-type']
        print r.encoding
        print r.text

doit("usernameas","qwerty")
```

Any idea about what's going on? The first script works; while the second does not. All I did was clean it up.
I wanted to have it so I could use the session over and over in different methods.

The second script does work with login, so it seems the session is fine but the second action doesn't work as intended even though it is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the two examples seem to be using different parameters, but the only significant difference I can see is between this line in the first example...

```
param = {'someID': '225', 'anotherID': '0'}
```

...and this line in the second example...

```
self.doAction(spSession, 33, 4)
```

...where the first is using strings for its parameters, and the second is using integers. Does it make any difference if you change the second line to...

```
self.doAction(spSession, '33', '4')
```

...?